# How to migrate Kotlin from 1.2 to Kotlin 1.3.0 then using async, UI, and bg in a presenter function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using MVP pattern on a Kotlin Project. I have a Presenter class:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.android.UI
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.async
import org.jetbrains.anko.coroutines.experimental.bg

class TeamsPresenter(private val view: TeamsView,
                     private val apiRepository: ApiRepository,
                     private val gson: Gson
) {
    fun getTeamList(league: String?) {
        view.showLoading()

        async(UI){
            val data = bg {
                gson.fromJson(apiRepository
                    .doRequest(TheSportDBApi.getTeams(league)),
                    TeamResponse::class.java
                )
            }
            view.showTeamList(data.await().teams)
            view.hideLoading()
        }
    }   
}
```

this presenter class working fine on Kotlin 1.2.71, but I can't get it working on Kotlin 1.3.0.

I updated Kotlin version in project's build.gradle, removed "experimental coroutines" and added kotlin coroutine core dependency:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.0'
```

and this is my current code:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson

class TeamsPresenter(private val view: TeamsView,
                     private val apiRepository: ApiRepository,
                     private val gson: Gson
) {
    fun getTeamList(league: String?) {
        view.showLoading()

        async(UI){
            val data = bg {
                gson.fromJson(apiRepository
                    .doRequest(TheSportDBApi.getTeams(league)),
                    TeamResponse::class.java
                )
            }
            view.showTeamList(data.await().teams)
            view.hideLoading()
        }
    }
}
```

Error mainly on async, UI, and bg function:

```
unresolved reference: async
unresolved reference: UI
unresolved reference: bg
```

How can I get this to work on Kotlin 1.3.0? for any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: This migration guide might be helpful: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md#migration-to-100-version-with-kotlin-13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has several layers of problems:

1. You're using `async`, but you don't `await` on it. You should be using `launch` instead.
2. You're using the pre-coroutines facility of `bg`, equivalent to `async`
3. You immediately `await` on `bg`, which means you should be using `withContext(Default)` instead
4. (new with Kotlin 1.3) You aren't applying [structured concurrency](https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952)

This is how your code should look in Kotlin 1.3:

```
fun CoroutineScope.getTeamList(league: String?) {
    view.showLoading()
    this.launch {
        val data = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            gson.fromJson(apiRepository.doRequest(TheSportDBApi.getTeams(league)),
                    TeamResponse::class.java
            )
        }
        view.showTeamList(data.teams)
        view.hideLoading()
    }
}
```

You should call your function with the coroutine scope appropriate to your situation. A typical approach is tying it to your activity:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    lateinit var masterJob: Job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + masterJob

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        masterJob = Job()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        masterJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you must use GlobalScope.launch instead of launch ,GlobalScope.async instead of async
Dispatcher.main instead of UI

[coroutineBasics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html)

Comment: Why so?  It is described differently here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html

Comment: please read this page https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html

Comment: are `Dispatchers.main` and `EmptyCoroutineContext` equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

Also add

`implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'`

Here is a fix ( I don't know if it is the best way to do it) :

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class TeamsPresenter(private val view: TeamsView,
                     private val apiRepository: ApiRepository,
                     private val gson: Gson
) {
    fun getTeamList(league: String?) {
        view.showLoading()
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            val data = async {
                gson.fromJson(apiRepository
                    .doRequest(TheSportDBApi.getTeams(league)),
                    TeamResponse::class.java
                )
            }
            view.showTeamList(data.await().teams)
            view.hideLoading()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even with the `implementation` line in, any import with `kotlinx.` other than `kotlinx.android` comes up as red and won't compile.